# How to get resouce in eclipse jdt-apt environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, annotation-processing

I'm developing an annotation processor. And here is a classic maven project structrue.

```
project
- src/main
  - java // SOURCE_PATH
  - resources // SOURCE_PATH
- target
  - classes // CLASS_PATH and CLASS_OUTPUT
  - generated-sources
    - annotations // SOURCE_OUTPUT
```

Everything is ok in maven with javac. But when I want to intergrate it into eclipse, [I find eclipse apt only support `CLASS_OUTPUT` and `SOURCE_OUTPUT`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/blob/2962b8046538b4b93a43217fb38e5c7a44afdafc/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/apt/pluggable/core/filer/IdeFilerImpl.java#L165).

I think `CLASS_OUTPUT` is also ok because it's equals to `CLASS_PATH`. Then I get the following exception

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/test-annotation-use-processer/target/classes/config.properties' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.filer.IdeInputFileObject.openInputStream(IdeInputFileObject.java:86)
```

Well, the file does exists in disk. I don't know what's wrong for eclipse.

Is there any workaround to get resource in eclipse apt?

Comment: Did you create/import the project as a maven project in Eclipse?  Eclipse has built-in support for maven projects.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Of course. The problem is about 'the built-in support'.

Comment: do you really keep you 'test-annotation-use-processer' project in the file-system root? Since path to the resource in the stack-trace starts with '/', means that this is an absolute path, not relative to your working dir, right?

Comment: @andrii The string (resource uri) is given by `Filer`. I think it is relative to eclipse workspace (a vitrual path). If not, it is a bug for eclispe.